# Disabling Rails' db:reset task

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To avoid an accidental 'rake db:reset' on our production environments, I was thinking about disabling 'rake db:reset' and related tasks that drop the database in the production environment.  Is there an easy way to do this, or do I have to redefine the rake task?

Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 7):

In your Rake file you can add

```
Rake.application.instance_variable_get('@tasks').delete('db:reset')
```

and the command is not available any more. If you want to disable multiple commands, put it in a `remove_task` method for readability.

But a better alternative seem to just not type the `rake db:reset` command, which is not something you'd accidentally type.

Having a nice backup of your (production) database is also a better solution I suppose.

Comment: I second the backups, not to mention locking down your production environment so only a couple people have access.

Comment: Veger: "But a better alternative seem to just not type the rake db:reset command" ... ideally, yes, but rake tasks can call each other, so sometimes being extra cautious is warranted.

Comment: @Veger `Rake::Task['db:reset'].clear_actions` is 'nice' in that it  'zeros' out the task but still allows it to be listed by `rake -T` and called. This can be good or bad.

Answer (score 2):

Put this in lib/tasks/db.rake:

```
if Rails.env == 'production'
  tasks = Rake.application.instance_variable_get '@tasks'
  tasks.delete 'db:reset'
  tasks.delete 'db:drop'
  namespace :db do
    desc 'db:reset not available in this environment'
    task :reset do
      puts 'db:reset has been disabled'
    end
    desc 'db:drop not available in this environment'
    task :drop do
      puts 'db:drop has been disabled'
    end
  end
end
```

Found [here](https://coderwall.com/p/jt4e1q/disable-destructive-rake-tasks-by-environment).

Answer (score 1):

Append this on your Rakefile.

```
namespace :db do
  task :drop => :abort_on_production
end
task :abort_on_production do
  abort "Don't drop production database. aborted. " if Rails.env.production?
end
```

It also blocks `rake db:reset` and `rake db:migrate:reset` because they call `db:drop`

Answer (score 0):

You could always overwrite the db:reset task with something like this in lib/db.rake:

```
namespace :db do
  desc 'Resets your database using your migrations for the current environment'
  task :reset do
    if RAILS_ENV == 'production'
      Rake::Task["db:drop"].invoke
      Rake::Task["db:create"].invoke
      Rake::Task["db:migrate"].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I don't think is going to work. "By default Rake Tasks append behavior every time they are defined" according to http://blog.jayfields.com/2008/02/rake-task-overwriting.html. So your attempt to "overwrite" the reset will fail. The reset will still happen. Right?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, We have an application linking into our live production database, we use test login details and from there shard's to out test DB.

The last thing we wanted was for rails to wipe out or database schema when running rspec/unit tests.

use the information is this question and here: [Is it possible to get a list of all available rake tasks in a namespace?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415159/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-all-available-rake-tasks-in-a-namespace)

I was able to come up with the following solution:

```
Rake.application.in_namespace(:db){|x|
  x.tasks.map{|t|
    Rake.application.instance_variable_get('@tasks').delete(t.name)
  }
}
```

This placed into the end of our Rakefile enabled us to remove all db: rake tasks as can be seen here:

```
[davidc@david-macbookp app1{master}]$ rake -T db
[davidc@david-macbookp app1{master}]$
```

With a little tweaking this could be done to disable on a per environment basis

**Update:**

Word of warning doing this for db namespace broke testunit and was required to add the addison:

```
namespace :db do
  task 'test:prepare' do
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use the [rails_db_protect gem](https://github.com/mojotech/rails_db_protect).

You just add the gem and it automatically prevents you from running the following dangerous tasks in production:

```
db:setup db:reset db:drop db:create db:schema:load
```

If you have a production environment, like a staging environment, where you want to be able to run these tasks, you can configure the environment to allow it:

```
ENV['ALLOW_DANGEROUS_TASKS'] = 'true'
```

There is also the gem [rails-safe-tasks](https://github.com/adamcooke/rails-safe-tasks) which allows more configuration but does not appear to have any tests supporting it.