# Is it possible to get a list of all available rake tasks in a namespace?

Tags: ruby, rake

Is it possible *from within a rake task* to get a list of tasks in a namespace? A sort of programatic 'rake -T db' ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I've found out the answer:

```
tasks = Rake.application.tasks
```

This will return an array of Rake::Task objects that can be examined.  Further details at http://rake.rubyforge.org/

Comment: As far as i have seen, there is no helper for finding things within a scope, but i think, that this should be easy enough:  Rake.application.tasks.reject{|task| task.scope != [:your, :scope] }

Comment: In my case (Rails), it was also necessary to run `AppName::Application.load_tasks` to populate `Rake.application.tasks`

Comment: _NOTE: This works from within a rake task, but not in a `rails console`._  (That's not a criticism—the question is specifically about getting this info within a rake task, but it surprised me, so I think it's worth noting for future readers.)

Answer (score 14):

As you wrote, with Rake.application.tasks you get all tasks.

But inside the namespace, you can select only the tasks of the namespace (task mytest:tasklist)

And you may restrict the tasks to a namespace (task tasklist_mytest).

```
require 'rake'

namespace :mytest do |ns|

  task :foo do |t|
    puts "You called task #{t}"
  end

  task :bar do |t|
    puts "You called task #{t}"
  end

  desc 'Get tasks inside actual namespace'
  task :tasklist do
    puts 'All tasks of "mytest":'
    puts ns.tasks #ns is defined as block-argument
  end

end

desc 'Get all tasks'
task :tasklist do
  puts 'All tasks:'
  puts Rake.application.tasks
end

desc 'Get tasks outside the namespace'
task :tasklist_mytest do
  puts 'All tasks of "mytest":'
  Rake.application.in_namespace(:mytest){|x|
    puts x.tasks
  }
end

if $0 == __FILE__
  Rake.application['tasklist'].invoke()  #all tasks
  Rake.application['mytest:tasklist'].invoke() #tasks of mytest
  Rake.application['tasklist_mytest'].invoke() #tasks of mytest
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the grep command like this

```
desc 'Test'
task :test do
    # You can change db: by any other namespaces
    result = %x[rake -T | sed -n '/db:/{/grep/!p;}' | awk '{print$2}'] 
    result.each_line do |t|
        puts t # Where t is your task name
    end
end
```

Comment: is this really the only possible solution to find tasks within a scope?!

Comment: Shelling out is really slow, why do it the round about way?