# Run all rake tasks?

Tags: ruby, rake, rake-task, rakefile

How can I run all rake tasks?

```
task :a do
    # stuff
end
task :b do
    # stuff
end
task :c do
    # stuff
end

task :all do
    # Run all other tasks?
end
```

I know I can just do

```
task :all => [:a, :b, :c] do
end
```

but if I add new task, I also need to add it to `:all` dependencies. I would
like to avoid the need to do it manually since it seems like easy thing to forget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
namespace :hot_tasks do |hot_tasks_namespace|
  task :task1 do
    puts 1
  end
  task :task2 do
    puts 2
  end
  task :all do
    hot_tasks_namespace.tasks.each do |task|
      Rake::Task[task].invoke
    end
  end
end
```

running it:

```
# bundle exec rake hot_tasks:all
1
2
```

More (not necessarily better) ideas at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3415159/is-it-possible-to-get-a-list-of-all-available-rake-tasks-in-a-namespace), especially if you're in a rails app.

Comment: 1) won't that recursively invoke `:all` task as well? If not why not? 2) If I don't need namespaces, `tasks.each ...` would suffice?

Comment: 1) nah, rake de-duplicates tasks pulled in as dependencies, so if you invoke  :all, invoking it again programmatically will not run it again. 2) if you don't want namespaces, Rake.application.tasks.each can work.